# How to point naked domain and www to the same Heroku app?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, cname, heroku

I create a simple Rails app and deployed it to Heroku. [This is my app](http://theorderapp.herokuapp.com/). I use Cloudflare to manage my DNS records and I try to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is all my current DNS records inside my Cloudflare:

[image]

**My problem**:

When I go to `ordr.my`, it's works like I wanted to.
But when I go to `www.ordr.my`, it returns `This webpage is not available` error (I'm using Chrome browser).

Am I doing any mistakes here?

How to achieve something like inside the image above?

**Note**:

I did my research by reading Heroku and CloudFlare docs. But I found no luck since I'm not able to understand them very clearly.

Reference:

1. [Heroku Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)
2. [Cloudflare Zone Apex](https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/)
3. [Cloudflare CNAME Flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)

Comment: Looks like it's working just fine, both www.ordr.my and ordr.my

Comment: It's working now @TimoLehto. Just updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I added `www.ordr.my` into my Heroku custom domain section and change `ordr.my` CNAME (root domain) to my Heroku app just like below:

**Cloudflare**

[image]

**Heroku**

[image]

Comment: So the problem wasn't your DNS setup. Heroku wasn't replying to the requests because the www version wasn't set up in their system. You had your DNS configured correctly.

Comment: Correct @SherwinFlight.